# RH_RF24_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN in RH_RF24.h

Tags: library, communication, wireless

I use  [`RH_RF24.h`](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/classRH__RF24.html) to control Si4463, and realize some simple communication between two Si4463 . But I don't know the mean of `RH_RF24_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN` in this [example](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/rf24_client_8pde-example.html).

`RH_RF24_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN` is a constant ? If so , what decides it ? And if I need to sent and receive  a long  char string , how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

`RH_RF24_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN` is probably defined in the header file RH_RF24.h.

It doesn't matter what size it is, you should always use `RH_RF24_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN` rather than the number because the value might change in the library and this will break your code if you have used the number.

If you want to send a message that is larger than `RH_RF24_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN` then you will need to 'fragment' the message (unless the library supports that).
I would use the first byte of the message as the type of message and define one of those types as a multi part string.  Then send a number of these message and reassemble the data on the receiver. When the receiver sees a message that contains a character with the ASCII value 0 then that is the end of the string.