# Speed of comunication by SI4463 under RH_RF24.h

Tags: library, communication, wireless, rf

As in this [SO question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/31064/28084), I use use a [RH_RF24.h](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/classRH__RF24.html) to control an [SI4463](https://www.silabs.com/products/wireless/EZRadioPRO/Pages/Si446x.aspx). In RH_RF24, there is not anything about the speed of communication. I need the way to control the speed of communication. Because I want to take high speed of communication when Rssi is strong and slow speed when weak (for reliability).

How should I to do it ?

Comment: Brief look at the docs suggest you define the modem config (modulation type and speed) using one/some of these values : http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/structRH__RF24_1_1ModemConfig.html

Comment: @KennetRunner  Thanks. Seemly , I can use setModemRegisters(prop_2003) , or  prop_2004, prop_2005 to set data rate (in fact, I am not sure whether I can do so ). But , I don't know the data rate of them .For example , what is the data rate of prop_2004, how to find it ?  Besides, when I low data rate, whether rate of messy code will become low ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RH_RF24.h](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/classRH__RF24.html) `setModemRegisters` takes a `ModemConfig` struct.  `prop_2003`, `prop_2004` and `prop2005` are part of that struct and it's the value of these 3 bytes that sets the datarate.

Datarate is a **24bit unsigned value** (hence the 3 bytes in the struct). `prop_2003` is the **MSB** and `prop_2005` the **LSB**.

- `prop_2003` default is `0x0F`
- `prop_2004` default is `0x42`
- `prop_2005` default is `0x40`

meaning the default data rate is `0x0F4240` ( = 1Mbps)

[This application note](http://community.silabs.com/mgrfq63796/attachments/mgrfq63796/BluetoothandWiFi/8086/1/Si446X%20API%20DESCRIPTIONS.pdf) on the API gives more details (around page 99).

Comment: What is the mean of 1Mhz ? It means I can communicate by speed of 1000000 bps ? But I rember the speed of SI4463 is slow. Besides , how to use setModemRegisters ?  For example ,because datarate is a 24bit unsigned value . How to write parameter of setModemRegisters ? Just setModemRegisters(prop_2003, prop_2004,prop_2005)   ?

Comment: Or just setModemRegisters(0x0F4240)   ? And could you help me in this question http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/31150/how-to-use-setmodemregistersin-rf24 ? Thanks very much.