# How to use setModemRegisters in RF24

Tags: library, wireless, rf, arduino-mini

The below picture is the introduction of [setModemRegisters](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/classRH__RF24.html#afd00202f768b4f0f893f2fbb9e650c7b) .

- First: What is the mean of **ModemConfig* config**? I mean: how to write the parameter. Maybe just give a example, and it will be better if it's suitable for this [SO question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/31122/28084).
- Second: What is the mean of data rate? It is the speed of SPI between the [SI4463](https://www.silabs.com/products/wireless/EZRadioPRO/Pages/Si446x.aspx) and MCU or speed of two SI4463  ?
- Third, What is the mean of bandwidths? I never saw it...

Thanks for any help .

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ModemConfig * config** is a pointer to a `ModemConfig` struct.

You need to create a `ModemConfig` struct, populate it then pass a pointer to it in the call to the `setModemConfig()` function.

Something like this:

```
// create the struct
ModemConfig mc = ModemConfig();

... //populate the struct values

// then call the function
setModemConfig(&mc);
```

The **datarate** is the rate at which you are sending information over the radio channel (**not** between the MCU and the Si4463).

The **bandwidth** is the range of frequencies used in the radio transmission (e.g. in [FSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying) if a *low/0* is 99.95MHz and a *high/1* is 100.05Mhz then the bandwidth would be 100Khz)

Comment: Thanks very much . I write a code in below . Is it right ?